# Bluemix android app .. no applicationId was specified exception

Tags: android, ibm-cloud

I want to run an android app using bluemix. I followed these steps:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-android-mobiledata-app/index.html#N10131

But I'm facing an exception saying that the Application ID is not found:

> Exception: 07-21 13:03:04.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
>   com.ibm.bluelist.BlueListApplication:
>   com.ibm.mobile.services.core.internal.IBMBluemixException:
>   IBMBLUEMIX-0042E: Initialization failed because

I have used my own Application ID, secret and route but I'm still getting this error. Can any one please help on this?

Comment: I guess the error message you posted is truncated, isn't it?

Comment: nope that was in the logs.

Comment: Do you mean you have specified the appid, app secret and route as defined in your Bluemix application? and those properties have been set in the bluelist.properties file? Double check those properties are correct and make sure the route is defined without the http:// at the front.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Message ID, I think this is the full error message.

"Initialization failed because no applicationId was specified"

@whitfiea is correct. You need to make sure the AppID is correctly specified for the Mobile Cloud application you are trying to reach (as well as check the other values, the appSecret and the appRoute).

The appRoute should be something like "BlueList.mybulemix.net"

I would also suggested downloading a new set of IBM Client SDK for Android JARs for your project. I would also recommend downloading a new copy of the BlueList sample from JazzHub, as corrections have been made to the application.

One final suggestion, create a new Mobile Cloud Application Backend, just to make sure you are at the current code levels for the client-side and the cloud side.

Answer (score 0):

1.Please try applicationRoute in bluelist.properties file without any prefix like http.

2. Make sure your application is of type Mobile Cloud under boilerplates.
3. Verify the below step given in  article.

Your Android app will need basic network capability and permissions, so we've included the following permissions in the manifest file. Open up the AndroidManifest.xml file to take a look.

Thanks.